# Воспроизведение m3u8 файлов

Tags: android, java, потоки-данных, видео

Как воспроизвести m3u8 файл в android 2.3.3?

Имеется ввиду воспроизведения потокового видео в таком формате

Comment: @mustache, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
 videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
 videoView.requestFocus();      
 videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener()
                    {

                          public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                          {     
                              mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
     videoView.start();}}});
    videoView.setVideoURI("your url to m3u8");
```

Answer (score 0):

m3u это текстовый формат списков воспроизведения с кодировкой latin-1 а m3u8 это тот же самый m3u с кодировкой utf8 вам нужно написать собственный парсер. Подробнее [M3U wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U)
 Потоковое видео абсолютно так же парситься адрес из m3u файла и воспроизводиться поток по указанному адресу...